# Python Uudecode Call Corruption

Tags: python, pdf, subprocess, corrupt, uudecode

I am working on extracting PDFs from SEC filings. They usually come like this:

[SEC Filing Example](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1508677/000000000014050442/0000000000-14-050442.txt)

For whatever reason when I save the raw PDF to a .text file, and then try to run

`uudecode -o output_file.pdf input_file.txt`

from the python `subprocess.call()` function or any other python function that allows commands to be executed from the command line, the PDF files that are generated are corrupted. If I run this same command from the command line directly there is no corruption.

When taking a closer look at the PDF file being output from the python script, it looks like the file ends prematurely. Is there some sort of output limit when executing a command line command from python?

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you run: `python -muu -d input_file.txt output_file.pdf` from the command line?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian When I ran that in the command line it worked. But as soon as I put it into my code like this :

`subprocess.call([ "python", "-muu", "-d", input_file.txt, output_file.pdf])`

I have the same issue

Comment: don't run it as a subprocess inside your Python script, you could import it instead: [`import uu; uu.decode('input_file.txt', 'output_file.pdf')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uu.html#uu.decode) (Note: the quotes around the filenames are not optional; they create a string object in Python). Or (better) pass open binary file objects e.g., created using `input_file = open('input_file.txt', 'rb'); output_file = open('output_file.pdf', 'wb')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script worked fine for me running under Python 3.4.1 on Fedora 21 x86_64 with uudecode 4.15.2:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("uudecode -o output_file.pdf input_file.txt", shell=True)
```

Using the linked SEC filing (length: 173,141 B; sha1: `e4f7fa2cbb3422411c2f2968d954d6bb9808b884`), the decoded PDF (length: 124,557 B; sha1: `1676320e1d9923e14d19451c16688198bc93ca0d`) appears correct when viewed.

There may be something else in your environment causing the problem.  You may want to add additional details to your question.

> Is there some sort of output limit when executing a command line command from python?

If by "output limit" you mean the size of the file being written by `uudecode`, then no.  The only type of "output limit" you need to worry about when using the `subprocess` module is when you pass `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` when creating a child process.  If the child process writes enough data to either of these streams, and your script does not regularly drain them, the child process will block (see the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module documentation).  In my test, `uudecode` wrote nothing to `stdout` or `stderr`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using Python 2.7.3, Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS), uudecode 4.11. I may try updating to uudecode 4.15 to see if that helps my issue.

edit: **I dont think python 2.7 can update to uudecode 4.1**

Comment: Can you check the return value of `subprocess.call()` in your script?